# pytest - minimal maintenance for parametrization of "multiplication table" results

Tags: python, parameters, combinations, pytest

I want to parametrize test for 2 input values and single output value which can be compared to testing multiplication table. To achieve minimal maintenance I came up with something like this:

```
results = [[ 4,  5,  6],
           [ 8, 10, 12],
           [12, 15, 18]]

@pytest.mark.parametrize("x, ix", [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2)])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y, iy", [(4, 0), (5, 1), (6, 2)])
def test_multiplication(x, ix, y, iy):
    assert x * y == results[ix][iy]
```

Now, this is not ideal because if I wanted to add new `x` then I will have to add `len(y) + 1 + 1` values which are: 3 new expected values, additional `x` value **and** index. The ideal would be adding only 4 values i.e. without control variable for the index.
I also don't like how `results` are kind of separated from the test function. The ideal would be:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [1, 2, 3])
@pytest.mark.parametrize("y", [4, 5, 6])
@pytest.mark.result_matrix("result", [
    [ 4,  5,  6],
    [ 8, 10, 12],
    [12, 15, 18],
])
def test_multiplication(x, y, result):
    assert x * y == result
```

I'm aware that I can add support for such `result_matrix` marker myself. But can I achieve the same using existing tools? Please, take into consideration the solution which will work well for the potentially infinite number of input parameters.

Comment: Parametrize with a single marker of three-tuples?

Comment: @ev-br Then input values for `x` and `y` will be duplicated.

Comment: this is not a problem if you have a dedicated contructor for the fixture

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a solution for truly an infinite number of parameters, but you can try the following:

1) just as @ev-br suggests,supply all the functions parameters in one `parametrize` statement, but you have to prepare them before that in a constructor for these arguments.

2) do the same in `for` loop over same argunenments. It is less fancy than `mark.parametrize`, but often more readable.

3) make your test parametrisation or `for` loop accept a list of dictionaries with arguments and result:

```
# code under test
def foo(x, y):
    return x * y

# need a constructor code for these test arguments and results
d0=dict(args=dict(x=2, y=3), result=6)
d1=dict(args=dict(x=5, y=10), result=50)
params = [d0, d1]

# test prototype - goes to pytest
for d in params:
    assert foo(**d['args']) == d['result']
```

I think this part is the closest to your concept of accepting a large number of arguements.

4) You might also want to check out [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) framework which operates on a concept of random testing, making the function verification more extensive.

Comment: This solution and the suggested three tuples require more maintenance because of possibly duplicated values for `x` and `y` but this makes tests less complicated than in my example with the index. I'm realizing that my ideal solution may not be so obvious to understand.

Comment: @JCode - the tests usually reveal the complexity of underlying code (more complex code under under test requires larger fixtures, their management, etc). Hard to see how you omit x and y if fucntion under test needs them to run (maybe there is an option to refactor it too). I think your problem lies in the fixture construtor, not in the better way of passing the args and result to test.

Comment: What is the "fixture constructor"? Where did that come from given that my and your code doesn't use pytest fixtures? OFC you can't omit values for `x` and `y` but my point is to specify values for them only once.

Comment: Fixture constuctor is any code you use to create your test inputs.